# Android Navigation Components

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I added Android new Navigation Component inside my app and created navGraph and added few fragments as a destinations. I figure out every time i navigates into destinations previous destination (fragment) is begin restarted. And my last state of previous destination (fragment) has lost. Is there any options to retain this?
As i already used `retainInstance` in fragment.

Comment: It's not restarted, it's *replaced*. It's the same as when you did `replace().addToBackStack()`. So the state of the Fragment should be exactly what it was, **but** the view is recreated.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks, Then how i maintain the state of my recyclerview view that is scrolled down by user?

Comment: The LayoutManager of the RecyclerView should persist and restore its state, and that is what stores the scroll position; meaning you shouldn't need to reload your data (especially not set an empty list as initialization) just because you navigated back.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the navigation component with fragments in my project and I found that the easiest way to save a fragment state is using the view model component: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI442XtIuR4wIVhuiaCh0uGAFZEAAYASAAEgIRIfD_BwE

I have been using MVP Architecture and in my model I extend the view model. 
That way as long as your activity wasn't destroyed the model instance is being saved and you can access it when the fragment reload so all it's parameters are still there so you can reinitialise your fragment with the saved values inside your model.